# Выравнивание span элементов по правому краю

Tags: html, css

Как можно выровнять эти цифры по правому краю?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
span.stats_post_infos {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 72%;
```

Comment: Может `text-align: right;`?

Comment: может, но увы оно не поможет :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text-align` - конечно хорошо, но `span` на него не реагирует, так как ширина `span` элемента по умолчанию равняется ширине контента внутри него.

Но выход есть:

```
display: inline-block;
width: (<максимально возможная ширина span>)px;
text-align: right или center
```

Comment: если что, ширину можно задать в процентах `width: 100%`